# OPENCV - Pixel count

Tags: opencv, drawing, pixel

I load an image in openCV. Then I draw line from Point(x1,y1) to Point(x2,y2). How to count the pixels on that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
int cvInitLineIterator(const CvArr* image, CvPoint pt1, CvPoint pt2, CvLineIterator* line_iterator, int connectivity=8, int left_to_right=0)
```

You can find its description [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/drawing_functions.html#initlineiterator)

"The function initializes the line iterator and returns the number of pixels between the two end points. Both points must be inside the image. After the iterator has been initialized, all the points on the raster line that connects the two ending points may be retrieved by successive calls of CV_NEXT_LINE_POINT point. The points on the line are calculated one by one using a 4-connected or 8-connected Bresenham algorithm."

Comment: I need to write in the language C #  in OpenCV wrapper

Comment: Then tag for your question is EmguCv.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lineiterator available in opencv

```
Point p1={x1,y1}; // point 1
Point p2={x2,y2}; // point 2
LineIterator lineIterator1(lineImg, p1, p2,8);
```

Once the line iterator is initialized then to find the number pixels present in the line joining `p1 and p2` use

```
lineIterator1.count
```

You can use either 4 or 8 connectivity for this line iterator.

you can find description of line iterator in the link below. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#LineIterator